# Async se cuelga al hacer consulta de entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Tengo un proyecto aspx en el uso el patrón repositorio, genérico, y estoy empezando a usar los métodos async que ofrece entity framework para interactuar con la base de datos, al intentar guardar un registro, siempre se queda colgado y no avanza el código.

Desde este método que está en el codebehind del aspx hago la petición de guardar a la base de datos a mi capa de negocios.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public async static Task<string> Guardar(TallerEntity item)
    {
        var classInstance = new Talleres();

        var message = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            await classInstance.GuardarAsync(item);
        }
        catch (TallerException ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = "Ocurrió un error, intente de nuevo";
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Message = message });
    }
```

Este método es que se llama y el intenta hacer el guardar del registro, primero consulta si el registro existe, si no existe lo creo si no, lo actualiza.

```
   public async Task<TallerEntity> GuardarAsync(TallerEntity item)
   {
        if (item.Nombre.Length == 0)
        {
            throw (new TallerException("Falta capturar el nombre"));
        }

        using (var r = new Repository<Taller>())
        {
            var saved = await r.RetrieveAsync(x => x.Codigo == item.Codigo);

            var isNew = saved == null;

            if (isNew)
            {
                saved = new Taller();
            }

            saved.Nombre = item.Nombre;

            if (isNew)
            {
                saved = await r.CreateAsync(saved);
                item.Codigo = saved.Codigo;
            }
            else
            {
                saved = await r.UpdateAsync(saved, x => x.First(y => y.Codigo == saved.Codigo));
            }
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Y en el método RetrieveAsync se cuelga cuando llega a la linea del FirstOrDefaultAsync, ya intenté poniendo el metodo ConfigureAwait(false) y aún así se sigue colgando.

```
    public async Task<TEntity> RetrieveAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        TEntity result;

        try
        {
            result = await EntitySet.Where(where).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Si en el método Guardar quito el async de Retrieve Async, llega hasta Create o Update y si hace la afectación a la base de datos, pero cuando llega al return sé queda colgado también.

```
    public async Task<TEntity> CreateAsync(TEntity toCreate)
    {
        TEntity result = null;
        try
        {
            EntitySet.Add(toCreate);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            result = toCreate;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

¿Alguien que tenga alguna idea de porque se cuelga?

Saludos

Comment: Solo una pregunta: Porque utilizas hilos en asp.net? No creo que sea necesario en el escenario que propones

Comment: Se supone que usar los métodos async de entity framework aprovecha mejor las capacidades del servidor y no es necesario, tengo tiempo desarrollando de esa manera sin hilos, pero intento optimizar los recursos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas poniendo un async en el lado del servidor, no es necesario ya que puede recibir varias peticiones simultaneas de igual manera, o sea no afecta nada

Y para la implementan te crea automáticamente la funcion async, cuando lo instancies, primero agrega la referencia, después desde código instancialo

```
WService.InstantLinkSoapClient ws = new WService.InstantLinkSoapClient();
```

Después cuando quieras usar algún método vas a tener ya creado vas a tener

```
ws.MiMetodo
ws.MiMetodoAsync
```